# sumProduct in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I'm trying implementing sumproduct (from excel) in my table on the server.

```
select * 
into #myTable2
from #myTable1

select
a, 
b,
c,
d,
e,
(
select (c * e)/100*3423) from #myTable1 t1
inner join #myTable t2
on t1.b = t2.b
where b like 'axr%'
) as sumProduct
from #myTable1
```

but this doesn't quite work. Can't spot the error, maybe i'm just tired or missing it.

**edit:**
sample data and desired results

will mention only the important columns

```
c     e    b        a                             sumProduct      
2     4   axr1     2012.03.01                     2*4 + 3*8 
3     8   axr3     2012.03.01                     2*4 + 3*8 
7     5   axr23    2011.01.01                     7*5 + 3*2
3     2   axr34    2011.01.01                     7*5 + 3*2
```

**EDIT2**:
I need some help with the syntax. I'm trying to rewrite this part:

```
select (c * e)/100*3423) from #myTable1 t1
    inner join #myTable t2
    on t1.b = t2.b
    where b like 'axr%'
    ) as sumProduct
    from #myTable1
```

as

```
case
when t.b like 'axr%' then
(sum(t.c * t.e) /100*3234) end as sumProduct from #myTable t
```

Can't get the syntax right, but should work like that

**edit 3:**
**got it to work** like this:

```
case
when b like 'axr%' then
(sum(c*e)/100*3423)end as sumProduct
```

and at the end of the code

```
group by  --had an error without this
a,b,c,d,e
```

How could i do this for every date (let's say the date is the column 'a' or whatever name). **How can I incorporate** `over (partition by a)` in the code above?

want something like

```
case 
when b like 'axr%' then
(sum(c*e)/100*3423 over (partition by a))end as sumProduct
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify your table.

Comment: remove last paren from select (c * e)/100*3423)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for a sum-product is very simple in SQL:

```
select sum(c * e)
from #mytable1;
```

I am not quite sure how this applies to your query, which seems to have other logic in it.

EDIT:

You want a window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(c*e) over (partition by a)
from #mytable1;
```

Comment: please see the sample data, maybe it helps for you to understand what i want

Comment: need to write something like this: `case
when t.b like 'axr%' then
(sum(t.c * t.e) /100*3234) end as sumProduct from #myTable t` see my edit. @Gordon Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sincerely I haven't understood your piece of code. But assuming that you have two tables with values and a unique Id (for the join), then maybe my implementation can help you for inspiration:

```
-- create new DB or point to an existing one
use [test];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into table1 values (1, 5), (2, 10);
insert into table2 values (1, 2), (2, 4);

select sum(P.products) as sumproduct from
(select (t1.value * t2.value) as products from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id) as P
```

Comment: i want to make a sumproduct of the values of two columns for all which are of form `'axr%' `for all the dates. I am using a,b,c..etc because it's not revelant what they have in, i probably have a `"ambigous column name error"`. In my code you can see i have 1 table which i'm trying to join with itself since the first thing i wrote was: `select * 
into #myTable2
from #myTable1
` . Thank you for the code , it is helpful