# Over partition by 2 columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I took one of my previous exercises and added some complexity to it.
You can find my original problem under: [select case with "over partition by"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559536/select-case-with-over-partition-by)

The scenario: (using SQL Server 2012)

```
 create table #testing (b varchar (20), a date, c int, e int)

 insert into #testing (b,a,c,e)
 values
    ('xf_1m','2015-03-02','1','3'),
    ('xf_3m','2015-03-02','2','5'),
    ('xf_5y','2015-03-02','4','2'),
    ('xf_10y','2015-03-02','3','6'),
    ('ay_10y','2015-03-02','7','2'),
    ('adfe_1m','2015-03-02','2','5'),
    ('xm_1m','2013-02-01','7','2'),
    ('xf_15y','2013-02-01','1','8'),
    ('xf_20y','2013-02-01','10','1')
```

After using this query:

```
select
    b, a, c, e,
    substring (b, 1, CHARINDEX ('_', b) - 1) rnc,
    substring(b, CHARINDEX('_', b) + 1, LEN (b)) rnb,
    case 
        when b like 'xf%' then -- 
            (sum(c * e) over (partition by a )) end as sumProduct
into #testing2
from #testing

select 
    *,
    case 
        when b like 'xf%' then -- 
        (sum(c * e) over (partition by a )) end as sumProduct
into #testing3
from #testing2

select * 
from #testing3
```

I am getting this:

[image]

Only that now I want to calculate the sumProduct partitioned by rnc and date (column a). 
How to do this? I tried with group by, but i'm having troubles with the unequal number from the select and the number of items i'm grouping by.

So, I'd **like to re-write somehow like this**:

```
 (sum(c * e) over (partition by a and partition by rnc )) as sumProduct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using temporary tables, but you can partition by multiple columns just by including them in the `partition by` list:

```
select *,
       (case when b like 'xf%' 
             then sum(c * e) over (partition by a, rnd )
        end) as sumProduct
into #testing3
from #testing2;
```

Comment: so can i simply write it as: `sum(c * e) over (partition by a,rnc ) as sumProduct` ? Asking cause the case is no longer needed since now i'm filtering for the date and rnc

Comment: @viorelmunteanu . . . If you don't need the case, then remove it.